# If Condition doesn't work with fgets (STDIN) in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, fgets

When I use fgets (STDIN) and enter "Yes" in the console, it doesn't return "Works" why? What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$var = fgets(STDIN);
if ($var == "Yes") {
    echo "Works";
}
```

[image]

Comment: `var_dump($var);` and next time paste your code here, not image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input read using `fgets` includes line-end, `trim` variable before you compare

```
<?php

$var = fgets(STDIN);
if (trim($var) == "Yes") {
    echo "Works";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are awesome!